# Represent number of value repeats after decimal

Tags: notation

Is there a way to represent the number of times a value has repeated after a decimal point?

For example if I have:

```
0.9
0.99
0.999
```

Is there something like:

```
9E-1
9E-2
9E-3
```

That easily represents these values?

Comment: You could invent a notation... like say  $0.\overset{3}{\fbox 8}5\overset 4{\fbox 7}1$ to mean $0.888577771$, but you'd need to define it clearly.

Comment: @Joffan yeah that actually looks pretty easy to understand, assuming there is nothing already out there. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking very specifically at the sequence $0.9,0.99,0.999,\dots$.  You can recognize that this is the sequence $1-0.1^n$.  If you want three nines repeated, that's $1-0.1^3$.  If you want a hundred nines repeated, that's $1-0.1^{100}$, etc...